# From managed file ID to end-user link - neat and clean way?

Tags: theming, navigation, files

I have a structure in database, and I want it printed. So in hook menu I have entry with

```
'page callback' => 'mymodule_mystructure_display',
```

And in inc file I have

```
function mymodule_mystructure_display($id_structure) {
  $mystructure= something(); // Data preparation
  return $mystructure;
}
```

And I have all helpers set up so in mystructure.tpl.php I can simply use:

```
kpr($mystructure);
```

and it all works, so let me omit details for now, they are covered in [Examples for Developers](https://drupal.org/project/examples) anyway.

### The real struggle is with files.

In `$mystructure['files']` I have a nested array like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(26) "Display name of first file"
    ["fid"]=>
    int(34)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(27) "Display name of second file"
    ["fid"]=>
    int(62)
  }
}
```

where `["fid"]` corresponds to `{file_managed}.fid` field in Drupal's database.

**What's the cleanest way to output links to files, with `["name"]` used as link text?**

What I'm doing now is pretty dirty:

1. In `function mymodule_mystructure_display` I `foreach` or [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk) over files.
2. For each element, I take file id, and use this helper function on it:

   ```
   _uri_by_id($id) {
     $file = file_load($id);
     return $file->uri;
   }
   ```
3. Result is fed to [`file_create_url`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) function, and it's result is saved under `["url"]` index, to give me this array in `$mystructure['files']`:

   ```
   array(2) {
     [0]=>
     array(2) {
       ["name"]=>
       string(26) "Display name of first file"
       ["fid"]=>
       int(34)
       ["url"]=>
       string(50) "http://example.com/sites/default/files/example.pdf"
     }
     [1]=>
     array(2) {
       ["name"]=>
       string(27) "Display name of second file"
       ["fid"]=>
       int(62)
       ["url"]=>
       string(50) "http://example.com/sites/default/files/example.txt"
     }
   }
   ```
4. In mystructure.tpl.php I use [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) to print actual link:

   ```
   echo l($item["name"], $item["url"]);
   ```

This all works. But it feels bad. I was always a backend guy, my frontend knowledge is somehow lacking. But I'm sure there should be a shorter way from managed file ID to a link. So what would it be?

**Note:** value under `["name"]` is derived from `$mystructure`, it is not something taken directly from file object. This pretty much stopped me from using [`theme_file_link()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/theme_file_link/7). But even if it wouldn't be the problem, I still need to load file object manually to use [`theme_file_link()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/theme_file_link/7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd personally prefer something like this:

```
// Extract file IDs so we only run one file_load().
$fids = array_map($mystructure['files'], function($x) { return $x['fid']; });
$files = file_load_multiple($fids);

$build = array();
foreach ($mystructure['files'] as $file) {
  // Update the description
  $files[$file['fid']]->description = $file['name'];

  // Add to the build
  $build[] = array(
    '#theme' => 'file_link',
    '#file' => $files[$file['fid']],
  );
}

return $build;
```

A bit cleaner/more performant, and using as much core API as possible.